# Quebra de texto na notificação Android Usando FCM upstream

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Ao receber a notificação o texto não é exibido por completo, no final do texto é mostrado uma reticência, como resolver isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo o código de envio da notificação

```
enviaNotificacaoDenuncia("Sua Denúncia foi protocolada numero: "+getProcesso().getNumProcesso(), getProcesso().getDenuncia().getToken());
```

Abaixo o método utilizado para processar o envio.

```
public void enviaNotificacaoDenuncia(String mensagem, String token) {
        Sender sender = new Sender(apiKey);
        Message message = new Message.Builder()
                .addData("message", mensagem)
                //.addData("denuncia", getGson().toJson(denuncia, DetalheDenuncia.class))
                .build();
        try {
            Result result = sender.send(message, token, 3);

            System.out.println(result.getCanonicalRegistrationId());
            System.out.println(result.getErrorCodeName());
            System.out.println(result.getMessageId());
            //System.out.println(denuncia.getTokenGCM().substring(0, 10));


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao enviar notificação!\n"+e, "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        atualizaTabela();
                        desabilitaBotoes();
                        desabilitaCampos();
                        limpaCampos();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao enviar notificação!\n"+e, "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
         }
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Notificação enviada com Sucesso!", "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Classes utilizadas no App

FcmListenerService

```
    package com.t2ti.cardapiobalcao;

    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.RingtoneManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
    import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

    import java.util.Map;

    public class DenunciaFcmListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

        private static final String TAG = "CardapioFcmLS";


        // [START receive_message]
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
            if (message != null) {
                Map<String, String> data = message.getData();
                String notificationBody = data.get("message");
                Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + notificationBody);


                    sendNotification(notificationBody);

            }
        }
        // [END receive_message]

        /**
         * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
         *
         * @param message GCM message received.
         */
        private void sendNotification(String message) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            int color = getColor(R.color.blue_dark);//modificar cor da notificação
            Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle("Secretaria do Meio Ambiente")
                    .setColor(color)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        }

    }

InstanceIDListenerService

package com.t2ti.cardapiobalcao;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class DenunciaInstanceIDListenerService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "DenunciaInstanceIDLS";
    private static String token;

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is also called
     * when the InstanceID token is initially generated, so this is where
     * you retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        //TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        //intentService.sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

    }


    public void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
       /*
        try {
            File arquivoXml = new File(getFilesDir(), "pedido.xml");
            Serializer serializer = new Persister();
            DetalheDenuncia denuncia = new DetalheDenuncia();
            if (arquivoXml.exists()) {
                denuncia = serializer.read(DetalheDenuncia.class, arquivoXml);
            }
            denuncia.setTokenGCM(token);

            serializer.write(denuncia, arquivoXml);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */
        setToken(token);
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    }
```

RegistrationIntentService

```
package com.t2ti.cardapiobalcao;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.t2ti.cardapio.Constantes;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};
    private static String token;

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {
            // [START register_for_gcm]
            // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
            // are local.
            // [START get_token]

            String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);

            // Subscribe to topic channels
            subscribeTopics(token);

            // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
            // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
            // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Constantes.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
            // [END register_for_gcm]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Constantes.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Constantes.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    /**
     * Persist registration to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    public void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
       /*
        try {
            File arquivoXml = new File(getFilesDir(), "denuncia.xml");
            Serializer serializer = new Persister();
            DetalheDenuncia denuncia = new DetalheDenuncia();
            if (arquivoXml.exists()) {
                denuncia = serializer.read(DetalheDenuncia.class, arquivoXml);
            }

            denuncia.setTokenGCM(token);

            //serializer.write(denuncia, arquivoXml);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*
         */

        setToken(token);
        //return token;
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
     *
     * @param token GCM token
     * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
     */
    // [START subscribe_topics]
    private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("mytopic");
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
    // [END subscribe_topics]

}
```

InstanceIDListenerService

```
package com.t2ti.cardapiobalcao;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class DenunciaInstanceIDListenerService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "DenunciaInstanceIDLS";
    private static String token;

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. Note that this is also called
     * when the InstanceID token is initially generated, so this is where
     * you retrieve the token.
     */
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        //TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        //intentService.sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

    }


    public void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
       /*
        try {
            File arquivoXml = new File(getFilesDir(), "pedido.xml");
            Serializer serializer = new Persister();
            DetalheDenuncia denuncia = new DetalheDenuncia();
            if (arquivoXml.exists()) {
                denuncia = serializer.read(DetalheDenuncia.class, arquivoXml);
            }
            denuncia.setTokenGCM(token);

            serializer.write(denuncia, arquivoXml);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */
        setToken(token);
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    }
```

Comment: Não tem a ver com o modo que você envia, e sim com o modo que você cria a `Notification` para exibir. Por favor, poste o código onde você faz o `build` da notification

Comment: editei e postei as classes do lado do app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro do seu `FcmListenerService` adicione o atributo `setStyle` do `NotificationCompat`.

Ficará assim:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Secretaria do Meio Ambiente")
                .setColor(color)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Isso fará com que sua notificação fique expandida.

[Referência](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded)

Comment: Valeu LMaker me ajudou muito, a única mudança foi o new antes do notificationCompat ficando assim: setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))